# Не работает консоль node.js npm файлы не пишутся и не отправляются

Tags: javascript, node.js

[[image: не работает консоль]]
[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YTGNr.png)
то что делать

решение проблемы ошибки

Comment: скорее всего проблема в том, что у вас есть папка npm и винда не может отличить название папки от названия команды)

Comment: Скорее всего где-то пробелы в пути. А вообще много чего другого может быть: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42678759/npm-error-on-every-command-eexist-file-already-exists-mkdir-c-users-user-ap

Answer (score 0):

Полностью удалить node_modules каталог
и npm install снова